# thebibliography do not display references inside braces [ ]

Tags: bibliographies

I am using this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,peerreview,draftcls,onecolumn]{IEEEtran} %
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}
...
... policies \cite{1Engelman02FCC} ...
...
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
    \bibitem{1Engelman02FCC} Engelman, R. (2011) `A survey of common control channel design in cognitive radio networks', {\it Elsevier Physical Communication}, Vol. 4, pp. 26-–39.
...
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

and this is the result:

[image]

It displays references inside the parentheses but I want to display them inside the braces [ ].

Comment: Off-topic: The `subfigure` package is considered deprecated. Use the [subfig](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/) package instead.

Comment: try `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`

Comment: @EladDen - Your suggestion has three issues: (a) parentheses will still be used, instead of brackets; (b) The font size used in the bibliography won't be correct for the `IEEEtran` document class; and (c) one will get specious warnings because `natbib` is looking for a `\bibliographystyle` instruction. These warnings can, admittedly, be ignored in the present case; nevertheless, it's probably a good idea to point this out explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're building the bibliography "by hand", i.e., without the help of a utility such as BibTeX. If that's the case, you needn't load the `natbib` citation management package. By not loading this package, square brackets instead of round parentheses will be used to enclose the citation call-out markers.

If, for some reason, you believe you must load the `natbib` package, you should (a) set the options `square` and `numbers` and (b) also issue an instruction such as `\bibliographystyle{plain}` in the preamble. If you pursue this route, though, you'll find that LaTeX isn't using the correct (`\footnotesize`) font size for bibliographic entries. (The IEEEtran document class uses `\footnotesize` for the bibliography.)

Instead of loading `natbib`, you might consider loading the `cite` citation management package: doing so won't change the font size used in the bibliography. Or, as already suggested above, don't load a citation management package at all.