# \bibentry does not display reference using beamer

Tags: beamer, bibtex, bibentry

I use the beamer documentclass and it does not typeset a bibentry.

I have found some related answers but none of them is exactly my situation:

[Beamer and Bibentry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205112/beamer-and-bibentry)

[thebibliography do not display references inside braces [ ]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340046/thebibliography-do-not-display-references-inside-braces)

[Bibentry does not show cite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203482/bibentry-does-not-show-cite)

My code is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{url}
\author{Joe Smith \\ Famous University}
\date{February 2022}
\title{Clickbait title}

\begin{document}


\maketitle

\begin{frame}[fragile]{The starting point}

\begin{quote}
\bibentry{Famous-Author-Famous-Paper}
\end{quote}
\end{frame}



\nobibliography{../../../MyBibliography}
\end{document}
```

The starting point slide contains only the title. The cc.bbl file does contain the bibliographical entry, so bibtex has found it in my bib file. My Makefile is:

```
all:        cc.tex
            xelatex cc
            bibtex cc
            xelatex cc
            xelatex cc

clean:
            rm cc.{aux,bbl,blg,log,out,pdf}
```

What does cause this non-typesetting and how can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the empty extra slide at the beginning if you place `\nobibliography` inside of a frame environment, e.g.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{url}
\author{Joe Smith \\ Famous University}
\date{February 2022}
\title{Clickbait title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\nobibliography{../../../MyBibliography}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{The starting point}
\begin{quote}
\bibentry{Famous-Author-Famous-Paper}
\end{quote}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, if I put the \nobibliography command between \begin{document} and \maketitle, xelatex does typeset the reference, although it creates an empty slide at the beginning:

```
\begin{document}

\nobibliography{../../../MyBibliography}

\maketitle
```